# firefox iframe history

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-applications

In a web app we use IFRAME to let users select items for the parent page.

The problem is that FIREFOX (3.5) adds a copy of the same (parent) page to history each time IFRAME is opened.

The web app is using history.back() to go from parent page to one that called that page.

We can fix that by passing the "back" page as parameter from caller to callee.

Still BACK button remains broken (the user presses back button but remains in same page).

The other problem that is created is that we want some pages out of history. We do not want the user to go **back** to an **INSERT** page.

This is easily done with location.replace on the **INSERT** page when finished, but impossible on FIREFOX with many entries of the same **INSERT** page.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if your problem is same as I was having today, but...

When there is an iframe on the page and iframes src changes, the browser (FF 4.0 in my case) considers it to be a navigation and upon pressing the back button, it navigates one step back inside this iframe.

It however behaves differently when you create this iframe dynamically with javascript after the page is loaded. Consecutive changing of iframes src does not count as navigation and browser does not put any pages into history, resulting in expected behavior of back button.

Comment: I don't know if this was correct in 2011, but this isn't correct today if I am reading this correctly. Iframes must be replaced or created at the same time that the history event is modified. (in the same function chain) The back/forward event chain propagation mechanism thus does not add this newly created iframe in Firefox, and all is good.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that your entries are duplicated, go

```
history.back(-2)
```

or -3, or -4 if needed instead of `history.back() or history.back(-1)`.

But then, if I were you I'd try to ditch the iframes based solution and build something that doesn't involve them at all, since communication between iframes and a parent document tends to be a bug magnet-